# Fitting image to window - GTKmm

Tags: window, gtk, signals, gtkmm

I am writing a simple photo viewer in C++ using gtkmm and I can not sort out few things. I would like to fit the image which is displayed to window. To do do this, I have connected `signal_configure_event` to my fitting function. This works quite well, but now I have two another problems:

1. The signal is not sent while maximizing/minimizing the window, and image size is not updating. I have tried to fix this by connecting my resize function to `signal_window_state_event`, but it does not work because signal is sent *before* resizing the window and running my function makes no sense because it gets old Gtk::Image widget size parameters.
2. Similiar story is with loading first image while launching my app - when I connect `loadImage()` to `signal_show` of main window it is launched *before* the window is maximized and the image remains very small.

If anyone could give me some idea on how to do it properly, I will be very grateful. GTKmm documentation is really poor and I have no idea how to do it.

Code responsible for above actions is here (the rest is in the repository):
https://github.com/jjkrol/ZPR/blob/master/src/gui.cpp

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the size-allocate signal or overriding on_size_allocate()?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I've had a problem with this signal and forgot to try it again.

Comment: To me, `gtkmm` documentation is perfectly adequate in detail; everything I've needed to do, I've been able to distill from the reference manual combined with the tutorial. Maybe it wasn't quite so good in the past; I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to connect my function to `signal_size_allocate`, any other signal is unnecessary now. Thanks **ergosys**!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~